# custom html button code for a form

Tags: html

ttI know this is a lame question but in order to do it right i need your help.

this is my html code

```
<form name="form1" class="form1">
<fieldset>
    <legend>Subscription</legend>
    <label for="subname">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="subname" />
    <label style="padding-left:20px;" for="subemail">Your Email</label>
    <input type="text" name="subemail" />
</fieldset>
</form>
<div style="width:100%; font-size:14px;text-align:center;"><a href="#">Click here to subscribe</a>
</div>
<div class="subscribe"><a href="#"></a>
</div>
```

and here is the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/V8RB2/

how can i associate the "Click here to subscribe" text and the button with this form?

Comment: you should use some javascript.

Answer (score 1):

If i understood you correctly, you want to submit the form when the link is clicked. To do this, you'll have to use JavaScript.

A quick way of doing it is by telling the form to submit itself in the onclick attribute of the link.

```
<a onclick="form1.submit()" href="#">Click here to subscribe</a>
```

What happens is, that when the link is clicked, you trap its onclick event and then you tell form1 to submit itself.

Comment: two questions 1. will this form work, if a user has diabled javascript in his browser? 2. does this "a" code has to be inside that closing of <form> or it can be anywhere in the page?

Comment: this relies on javascript so it has to be enabled. And, no the a element doesn't need to be inside the form. However, if you want it to work regardless of JavaScript being off or not, why not use a submit input button. Just put this inside the form tag, `<input type="submit" value="Click here to subscribe" />`

Comment: there are two submit stuff... one is text link and another is image link as you can see in that fiddle...

Comment: Try this http://jsfiddle.net/hkc67/ It uses a submit input element and styles it using css to look and behave the same as the link element.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would make this a button within the form and use CSS to style it however you want.

```
<input type="submit" id="button1" class="button1" name="subscribe" value="Click here to subscribe!" />
```

Then to style:

```
form input.button1 {
   style here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The below will work.

```
<form name="form1" class="form1">
<fieldset>
<legend>Subscription</legend>
<label for="subname">Name</label>
<input type="text" name="subname" />
<label style="padding-left:20px;" for="subemail">Your Email</label>
<input type="text" name="subemail" />
</fieldset>
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="document.getElementByClass('form1').submit();">Click here to subscribe</a>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your link's href to:

```
href="javascript:document.forms['form1'].submit()"
```

Or add that as an onClick attribute.

Updating with a technique to route around disabled javascript.

```
<script>document.write('<a href="javascript:document.forms[\'form1\'].submit()">Click here to subscribe</a></div><div class="subscribe"><a href="#"></a>');</script><noscript><input type="submit" value="submit"></noscript>
```

Comment: two questions 1. will this form work, if a user has diabled javascript in his browser?
2. does this "a" code has to be inside that closing of <form> or it can be anywhere in the page?

Comment: If the user has disabled javascript, it will not work. In that case only a submit button will submit the form.

Comment: The link can be anywhere in the page. It does not need to be in the form itself.In the workaround, that code does have to be in the form because of the noscript tag, but you can replace the document.write() with a getElementById and use innerHtml() to write the link into a div or span somewhere else in the page.

Comment: erik I'll appreciate if you can help me with the updated fiddle, for both 1. text linked button and second the image button

Comment: Sorry, but I've provided you with directions you can take. We aren't here to write your code for you.